# Is there anyway to speed up this linked Server SQL update?

Tags: sql, linked-server

Is there a way to speed up this sql? I am using a linked server. I tried to do a merge and the performance was the same.

--Update Participants by recordModified Server 1 -> Server 2

```
update p1 
set  p1.[RecordCreated] = p2.RecordCreated
,p1.[RecordModified] = p2.RecordModified
,p1.[Email] = p2.Email
from ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant p1
join [Computer2\SqlExpress].ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant p2 
on p2.RecordModified >= (select LastSync from ERSS_DB_Sync) 
and p1.ParticipantID = p2.ParticipantID 
and p1.RecordCreated = p2.RecordCreated and p1.RecordModified < p2.RecordModified
```

I am updating over 35 columns, I left them out to simplify the query.

I added this in and it did NOT seem to help

```
 on p2.RecordModified >= (select LastSync from ERSS_DB_Sync)
```

The bottle neck seems to be the amount of columns that I am updating.

Is there anyway to speed up this update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local Sql Server doesn't know anything about statistics, number of records, or indexes on the remote/linked Sql Server. As is, it needs to bring over *all* of the records from the remote server to even do the check on the `RecordModified` column.

You may be able to improve things by using `OPENQUERY(), to let the linked remote server pre-filter the results before sending them to local server. This will limit network traffic just the relevant records and allow the remote server to use it's indexes as it builds the result set:

```
update p1 
    set  p1.[RecordCreated] = p2.RecordCreated
        ,p1.[RecordModified] = p2.RecordModified
        ,p1.[Email] = p2.Email
from ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant p1
join OPENQUERY([Computer2\SqlExpress], 
    'SELECT * FROM ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant  WHERE p2.RecordModified >= ''' + (select LastSync from ERSS_DB_Sync) + '''') p2 
  on p1.ParticipantID = p2.ParticipantID 
   and p1.RecordCreated = p2.RecordCreated 
   and p1.RecordModified < p2.RecordModified
```

Even better if you can also limit the columns returned by changing the `*` to just what you need.

Comment: This worked Great! I just had to pass it in as a string and then do Exec. Runs in less than 1 sec, where before took 45 secs... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
--assign a variable prevents some issues with query optimizer
DECLARE @LastSync DATETIME;
SELECT @LastSync = LastSync from ERSS_DB_Sync

update 
    p1 
set 
     p1.[RecordCreated] = p2.RecordCreated
    ,p1.[RecordModified] = p2.RecordModified
    ,p1.[Email] = p2.Email
from 
    ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant p1
    join (
            SELECT 
                [Computer2\SqlExpress].ERSS_Local.dbo.Participant  
            WHERE 
                RecordModified >= @LastSync
                -- force the destination engine to filter this set first
        ) as p2
    on p1.ParticipantID = p2.ParticipantID 
    and p1.RecordCreated = p2.RecordCreated and p1.RecordModified < p2.RecordModified
```